# gdbserver cant find static lib cources

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, cmake, gdbserver

I have the following setup :

1. I use visual studio 2019 as IDE and build a C++ project
2. I use cmake to compile and build my project
3. I build everything for linux
4. My code has two main folders proj/MyCode and proj/Framework
5. I link the Framework as static lib in MyCode
6. the -g compilation flag is set

When Im connecting to my linux machine after building and run MyCode using gdb locally everything works fine.
When Im trying to use gdbserver, I can debug MyCode.
When  Im trying to remote debug from visual to my linux machine,
I get "Frame not in module" error when Im trying to step into Framework code.
Debugging "MyCode" works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you are statically link the library, I think you can try the gdb command "**set directories**"

For your reference, if the library is dynamically linked, you need to "**set solib-search-path**"